# Como hacer una consulta en sql para obtener un campo ingresando varios parametros en el where

Tags: sql-server, subconsultas, sql

estoy haciendo una base de datos en sql sobre comidas. Las tablas que tengo son comidas de la costa sierra selva e ingredientes. Y sus tablas intermedias. Lo que quiero hacer es una consulta que me permita obtener una comida ingresando varios ingredientes en el where. No se si mi base de datos permita hacer esa consulta.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: porque hay una tabla diferente entre comidas de la costa o de la selva? que las diferencia? no pareceria ser correcta una db asi.

Comment: Por la relacion de muchos a muchos, una comida puede tener varios ingredientes y un ingrediente puede pertenecer a varias comidas.

Comment: @Jean, A tu diseño actual me parece que le falta una pizca de sal. Puedes tener una sola tabla de  `comida` que tenga un campo `region` o `tipo` que indique si es _de la sierra_, _de la selva_ o _de la costa_. De esta manera, se facilita realizar la consulta que quieres. De otra manera, hay que hacer la misma consulta 3 veces y unir los resultados. O bien, unir primero todas las comidas con sus ingredientes y finalmente realizar la consulta. En todo caso, conlleva más trabajo.

Answer (score 0):

si se puede pero, desde mi punto de vista, yo creo que hay que re-formular el DISEÑO: una tabla es considerada cuando tiene mas de 3 atributos; en el caso de la costa pues eso pertenece a `tabla region` que tiene id

```
select from ingredientes 
inner join comidaselva_ingredientes on ingredientes.id_ingredientes=comidaselva_ingredientes.id_ingredientes 
inner join comidas_de_la_selva on comidaselva_ingredientes.id_selva=comidas_de_la_selva.id_selva
inner join comidacosta_ingredientes on ingredientes.id_ingredientes where ingredientes.nombre_ingrediente = "cebolla"
```

faltarias hacer un `inner join` alas demas tablas de la sierra y la costa

Answer (score 0):

Prueba haciendo inner join a las tablas involucradas de la siguiente manera:

```
select ingredientes.nombre_ingrediente AS ingredientes from ingredientes 
    inner join comidacosta_ingrediente on ingredientes.id_ingrediente = comidacosta_ingrediente.id_ingrediente
    inner join comidas_de_la_costa on comidacosta_ingrediente.id_costa = comidas_de_la_costa.id_costa  
        WHERE ingredientes.nombre_ingrediente = "cebolla"
        AND ingredientes.nombre_ingrediente = "jitomate"
        AND ingredientes.nombre_ingrediente = "chiles"
```

Esepro te sirva, suerte!